Sodium increase in saltwater chlorination swimming pools
If I understand well the chemistry of a saltwater swimming pool (I’m not a chemist), over years, we add salt in the swimming pool. This is due to the fact that in Salt water chlorination, Chlorine gas is produced by electrolysis and consumed. Therefore, you need to add regularly salt to compensate chlorine consumption.
While the $\ce{Cl}$ concentration doesn’t increase due to the production of gases, the concentration of $\ce{Na}$ (sodium) increases year over year. Do I understand well? What are the consequences of this $Na$ increase? In terms of health? In other terms?
If I’m right, over the very long run, the swimming pool will be full of sodium!

Why would one add salt if the specific gravity is correct??? To simulate the Dead Sea?

The common mistake of non chemists is they do not distinguish 2 forms of occurrence of the chemical element chlorine. The elementary chlorine that is soluble gas, used for desinfection of pools, in concentration typically <10 mg/L. (or other chlorine compounds are used to release chlorine). And then there is chloride, what is a ion as counterpart to sodium ions in sodium chloride.  Sea water can contain up to roughly 25 g Cl-/L.

@DrMoishePippik Because in a saltwater chlorination swimming pool, electrolysis produces chlorine gas for disinfection. Therefore, the amount of chlorine decreases and you have to add salt regularly to compensate for that decrease. And my question is about the increase of sodium.

The electrolysis of your pool water would then make your water more basic, sodium hydroxide would indeed build up. You then add some pH regulator, which apparently is hydrochloric acid (looked this up). So you end up getting NaCl back. You don't continuously add NaCl and buildup sodium. If you would add some other acid to neutralize the sodium hydroxide I suppose you can remove excess sodium with reverse osmosis or other similar process.

@Noah Indeed, there is some PH regulator. However, I confirm that I have to add salt every year - around 75 kg for $20 m^3$ of water in my case.

Keep in mind that there can be no charge imbalance in a solution. If we add $\ce{NaCl}$ to water, $\ce{Cl-}$ cannot leave the solution, leaving $\ce{Na+}$ behind. This is electrostatically not possible. You might be mixing the idea of mixing water with a small amount of elemental chlorine (a gas) which was used to disinfect water. When dissolved in water it exists as hypochlorite and chloride ion. Modern disinfecting system would use something which generates hypochlorite ions in contact with water rather than handling the gaseous element.
Response to a comment:

$\ce{Cl−}$ leaves the solution due to the electrolysis used in a
saltwater swimming pool for disinfection. This is why salt needs to be
added regularly in such swimming pools... And my question is about the
increase of Na as a consequence.

The escape of chlorine from water will be pH dependent. This can be seen in something called speciation diagrams ResearchGate Paper. Above pH 6, there is no free chlorine in water and almost exists as hypochlorous acid.
Even if we assume there is some loss of Cl mass from the water during electrolysis, there will be a disbalance of the number of sodium and chloride ions (if we were to count and talk about mass balance), yet the electrostatic disbalance cannot occur. If $\ce{Cl-}$ leaves water in any form, another negatively charged ion has to replace it. This negative ion is provided by water as hydroxide, which means pool water will become basic with time, if we assume we lose Cl mass from water. However, after electrolysis, pool water pH is adjusted by acids to an appropriate value. The equations are already provided in your Wikipedia link.


$\ce{Cl-}$ leaves the solution due to the electrolysis used in a saltwater swimming pool for disinfection. This is why salt needs to be added regularly in such swimming pools... And my question is about the increase of $\ce{Na}$ as a consequence.
